# Loop every alternate column in table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

Is there a way to loop through every alternate column in a table?

I would like to loop through the TDs of a table but only those that are in columns `2, 4, 6 and 8`.

I could also add a class to the `THs` or `COLs` of these columns if that helps.

I am looking for something like the following (just to demonstrate):

```
$('#my table tbody (col2,col4,col6,col8)').each(function() {
    $('td').each(function() {
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```
$('#my table td:nth-child(even)').each(...);
```

If you want to stop at 8 even though there are more columns after that (as in David's answer), you can do it in a slightly more convoluted way:

```
$('#my table td:nth-child(-2n+8)').each(...);
```

(This works because only values n >= 0 are considered by `nth-child()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this supported in IE8 and IE9 ?

Comment: It's part of jQuery; it doesn't actually rely on the CSS `nth-child` selector being present. So it should work on any browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#table td:nth-child(2)").each(function (index) {
   alert('Row: ' + (index+1) + ', Col : ' + $(this).html());
});
```